# Hadoop Oozie Like Projects

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie-coordinator

Oozie is a workflow/coordination engine to orchestrate Hadoop jobs where Oozie Workflow jobs are Directed Acyclical Graphs (DAGs) of actions.

What are other Oozile like workflow engines to manage job chains on a cluster?

Is there a generic Oozile like workflow engine that is capable of orchestrating jobs any cluster through a plug-in or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although I personally prefer oozie you could also checkout [azkaban](http://sna-projects.com/azkaban/).

Comment: Is there any cross cluster workflow manager? I mean a workflow manager that can orchestrate jobs across mutli verndor clusters?

Comment: I used oozie in multistage environment (dev/prod); changing paths and configs for jobs using simple scripting. But for multi vendor you have only 1 option: you should write a wrapper for multiple oozie rest api. There is no workflow manager that supports multiple vendor as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

Hortonworks' NIFI is an awesome workflow engine which does what you are asking.